# JavaScript/React Native array(objects) sort

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm starting with react-native building an app to track lap times from my RC Cars. I have an arduino with TCP connection (server) and for each lap, this arduino sends the current time/lap for all connected clients like this:

```
{"tx_id":33,"last_time":123456,"lap":612}
```

In my program (in react-native), I have one state called `dados` with this struct:

```
dados[tx_id] = {
  tx_id: <tx_id>, 
  last_time:,
  best_lap:0,
  best_time:0,
  diff:0,
  laps:[]
};
```

This program connects to arduino and when receive some data, just `push` to this state. More specific in `laps` array of each transponder. Finally, I get something like this:

```
dados[33] = {
  tx_id:33,
  last_time: 456,
  best_lap: 3455,
  best_time: 32432,
  diff: 32,
  laps: [{lap:1,time:1234},{lap:2,time:32323},{lap:3,time:3242332}]
}
dados[34] = {
  tx_id:34,
  last_time: 123,
  best_lap: 32234,
  best_time: 335343,
  diff: 10,
  laps: [{lap:1,time:1234},{lap:2,time:32323},{lap:3,time:3242332}]
}
dados[35] = {
  tx_id:35,
  last_time: 789,
  best_lap: 32234,
  best_time: 335343,
  diff: 8,
  laps: [{lap:1,time:1234},{lap:2,time:32323},{lap:3,time:3242332},{lap:4,time:343232}]
}
```

This data in rendered to `View`'s using `map` function (not a FlatList). 
My problem now is that I need to order this before printing on screen.

Now, with this code, data are printed using `tx_id` as order, since it's the key for main array. Is there a way to order this array using number of elements in `laps` property and the second option to sort, use `last_time` property of element?

In this case, the last `tx` of my example (`35`) would be the first in the list because it has one lap more than other elements. The second item would be `34` (because of `last_time`). And the third would be `tx` `33`.

Is there any way to to this in JavaScript, or I need to create a custom functions and check every item in recursive way?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tks @crackhead420

While waiting for reply to this question, I just found what you said.... :)

This is my final teste/solution that worked:

```
var t_teste = this.state.teste;
    t_teste[33] = {tx_id: 33, last_time:998,best_lap:2,best_time:123,diff:0,laps:[{lap:1,time:123},{lap:2,time:456}]};
    t_teste[34] = {tx_id: 34, last_time:123,best_lap:2,best_time:123,diff:0,laps:[{lap:1,time:123},{lap:2,time:456}]};
    t_teste[35] = {tx_id: 35, last_time:456,best_lap:2,best_time:123,diff:0,laps:[{lap:1,time:123},{lap:2,time:456},{lap:3,time:423}]};
    t_teste[36] = {tx_id: 36, last_time:789,best_lap:2,best_time:123,diff:0,laps:[{lap:1,time:123},{lap:2,time:456}]};

    console.log('Teste original: ',JSON.stringify(t_teste));

    var saida = t_teste.sort(function(a, b) {
      if (a.laps.length > b.laps.length) {
        return -1;
      }
      if (a.laps.length < b.laps.length) {
        return 1;
      }
      // In this case, the laps are equal....so let's check last_time
      if (a.last_time < b.last_time) {
        return -1; // fastest lap (less time) first!
      }
      if (a.last_time > b.last_time) {
        return 1;
      }
      // Return the same
      return 0;

    });

    console.log('Teste novo: ',JSON.stringify(saida));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using some simple helper functions, this is definitely possible:

```js
const data = [{tx_id:33,last_time:456,best_lap:3455,best_time:32432,diff:32,laps:[{lap:1,time:1234},{lap:2,time:32323},{lap:3,time:3242332}]},{tx_id:34,last_time:123,best_lap:32234,best_time:335343,diff:10,laps:[{lap:1,time:1234},{lap:2,time:32323},{lap:3,time:3242332}]},{tx_id:35,last_time:789,best_lap:32234,best_time:335343,diff:8,laps:[{lap:1,time:1234},{lap:2,time:32323},{lap:3,time:3242332},{lap:4,time:343232}]}]

const sortBy = fn => (a, b) => -(fn(a) < fn(b)) || +(fn(a) > fn(b))
const sortByLapsLength = sortBy(o => o.laps.length)
const sortByLastTime = sortBy(o => o.last_time)
const sortFn = (a, b) => -sortByLapsLength(a, b) || sortByLastTime(a, b)

data.sort(sortFn)

// show new order of `tx_id`s
console.log(data.map(o => o.tx_id))
```

[`sortBy()` (more explanation at the link)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51398944/1541563) accepts a function that selects a value as the sorting criteria of a given object. This value must be a string or a number. `sortBy()` then returns a function that, given two objects, will sort them in ascending order when passed to `Array.prototype.sort()`. `sortFn()` uses two of these functions with a logical OR `||` operator to employ short-circuiting behavior and sort first by `laps.length` (in descending order, thus the negation `-`), and then by `last_time` if two objects' `laps.length` are equal.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to sort an object array by theire values:

```
dados.sort(function(a, b) {
   return a.last_time - b.last_time;
});
```